# Partially sorting collections in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, scala-collections

I am trying to sort a collection of linked-list nodes. The collection contains nodes from more than one linked list; ordering must be maintained within each list, but ordering across lists does not matter.

`PartialOrdering[T]` seems like the natural choice, but I cannot find any standard functions within Scala that support it (e.g. `.sort` only takes `Ordering[T]`).

I've considered wrapping the former type into the latter, but realise this will actually produce erroneous results. Partial ordering cannot be abstracted-away like this as the underlying sort algorithm needs the additional information to produce correct results.

I would like to represent the elements as a `SortedSet` - is anyone aware of anything that can get me close?

Comment: If it really doesn't matter what the order is across lists, why don't you keep them all separate and sort them independently?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure the problem you're trying to solve is linked to PartialOrdering. Moreover, do you have a collection of LinkedList or a collection of collections of LinkedList ? That's not really clear from your question :-(

Comment: I think the example can be simplified: nodes from the same linked list can only be compared in terms of `lt` (i.e. `!lt` does not imply `gt`). This produces an `Ordering[T]` that marks such incomparable elements as `0`, but those elements may not necessarily be `equal`, which I believe is not a legal implementation of `Ordering[T].compare`?